# How can I read this ASCII data without column name assigned using Python?

Tags: python, pandas, ascii

Please see the attached data file for its format, there are 6 header lines showing the information of the data matrix, in this case, 100 rows and 100 columns. I try to use the following codes:

`path = "ArcGIS.txt"
 data = pd.read_csv(path, sep=" ", header = 6, index_col = False, na_values = -9999)`

But the data I get is not 100 rows and 100 columns. I don't know how to upload attachment, so I just use an image to show the format (data is delimited by 'space'):

[data capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySZma.jpg)

Comment: how many rows and columns is it when you go that?

Comment: property of its shape is (99, 100)

Comment: Welcome to the site: you may want to read [help/on-topic], [ask] and [mcve], and re-word your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data = pd.read_csv(path, sep=" ", header = 5, names=[i for i in range(100)], na_values = -9999)
```

It should ignore the first 6 lines (header=5 for that), and then give columns names from 0 to 99

And you mentioned you wanted the header as well. I cant think of a way to do it with pandas, but here is a handy way:

```
path = "ArcGIS.txt"
params = dict()
with open(path, 'r') as f:
    for i in range(6):
        key, val = f.readline().split()
        params[key] = val
```

This will give you a dict with all of those parameters. Hope this works for you.

Comment: Thank you so much. Your code works. Another question is can I extract to the header information into separate variables, like number of rows?

Comment: @JianWang-CHN please mark the answer as accepted if it worked for you:) I'll give that a shot and update my answer with it

Comment: @JianWang-CHN I added a way of getting those, but it's not using pandas. hope it works

Comment: Thank you. That helps me a lot.